# Applying a Magrittr Pipe in lapply() with R

Tags: r, list, dplyr, magrittr

I would like to find a way to implement a series of piped functions through an lapply statement and generate multiple databases as a result. Here is a sample data set:

```
# the data
d <- tibble(
  categorical = c("a", "d", "b", "c", "a", "b", "d", "c"),
  var_1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  var_2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,1, 1),
  var_3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  var_4 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

Here is the outcome I want:

```
$var_1
a  b  c  d
1  1  1  1

$var_2
a  b  c  d
0  0  1  2

$var_3
a  b  c  d
1  2  2  1

$var_4
a  b  c  d
0  0  1  1
```

I can recreate each list element individually with ease. Here is my sample code with dplyr:

```
d %>%
  filter(var_1 == 1) %>%
  group_by(categorical, var_1) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  select(-var_1) %>%
  rename("var_1" = "n") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(categorical, var_1)

# A tibble: 1 x 4
      a     b     c     d
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     1
```

But, I want to automate the process across all columns and create an object that contains each row of information as a list.

Here is where I started:

```
lapply(d[,2:5], function (x) d %>%
  filter(x == 1) %>%
  group_by(categorical, x) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  select(-x) %>%
  rename("x" = "n") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(categorical, x))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `gather` into 'long' format, then do a `group_split` and `spread` it back after getting the `sum` of 'val' grouped by 'categorical'

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(d, key, val, -categorical) %>%
     split(.$key) %>%
     map(~ .x %>% 
           group_by(categorical) %>%
           summarise(val = sum(val)) %>%
           spread(categorical, val))
#$var_1
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#      a     b     c     d
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1     1

#$var_2
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#      a     b     c     d
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     0     1     2

#$var_3
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#      a     b     c     d
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     2     1

#$var_4
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#      a     b     c     d
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     0     1     1
```

---

Or another option is to loop through the columns except the first one, and then do the `group_by` `sum` and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
map(names(d)[-1], ~ 
          d %>%
           group_by(categorical) %>% 
           summarise(n = sum(!! rlang::sym(.x))) %>% 
           spread(categorical, n))
```

Comment: This first option worked best for me. I have a lot of NA values in my actual data set and adding `na.omit() %>%` after the `gather` step worked perfect.

Comment: @Craig  Okay, in the second version, you can use `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum`

Answer (score 0):

here is an option using `data.table::transpose()` :

```r
aggregate(. ~ categorical, d, sum) %>%
  data.table::transpose(make.names = "categorical") %>%
  split(names(d)[-1])
#> $var_1
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 1 1 1
#> 
#> $var_2
#>   a b c d
#> 2 0 0 1 2
#> 
#> $var_3
#>   a b c d
#> 3 1 2 2 1
#> 
#> $var_4
#>   a b c d
#> 4 0 0 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>